# How to achieve output of `kbl()` while hiding `kbl()` call?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto, kableextra

I want the displayed code to omit the `kbl()` as in the `tbl-without-kbl` chunk while producing output matches that of `tbl-with-kbl`. In short, I want the code that is displayed to be optimised for copy-pasting by the user (no `kbl()`), but for the actual output (in the book) to look good (with `kbl()`, it looks good in both HTML and PDF).

I have tried putting the `kableExtra::kbl()` call in the chunk options but the table doesn't look the same.

Is there any way to do this?

````
---
title: "Stuff with tables"
author: Ian D. Gow
format: pdf
---

```{r}
#| include: false
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
```

```{r}
#| label: tbl-with-kbl
#| tbl-cap: "Table with `kbl()`"
dt |> 
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE)
```

```{r}
#| label: tbl-without-kbl
#| tbl-cap: "Table without `kbl()`"
dt
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/opts-render.html) one option would be to use a custom print method like so:

````
---
title: "Stuff with tables"
format: pdf
---

```{r}
knit_print.data.frame <- function(x, ...) {
  res <- paste(c("", "", kableExtra::kbl(x, booktabs = TRUE)),
    collapse = "\n"
  )
  knitr::asis_output(res)
}

registerS3method(
  "knit_print", "data.frame", knit_print.data.frame,
  envir = asNamespace("knitr")
)
```

```{r}
#| include: false
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
```

```{r}
#| label: tbl-with-kbl
#| tbl-cap: "Table with `kbl()`"
dt |>
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE)
```

```{r}
#| label: tbl-without-kbl
#| tbl-cap: "Table without `kbl()`"
dt
```
````

[image]